# How to install dependencies not found in the repositories for JHBuild?

Tags: gnome, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, jhbuild

I have been following [this guide](https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers/BuildGnome) in order to set up JHBuild. And I have got up to the bit which says to execute:

```
jhbuild sysdeps --install
```

However there is a slight problem because upon running that I have found that it is unable to locate some of the packages needed to continue. And now that it has installed all that it can, this is the output from the command now (and every time I run it now this is the output):

```
    py3cairo (py3cairo.pc, required=1.10.0, installed=1.10.0)
    dbus (dbus-1.pc, required=1.4.10, installed=1.10.0)
    cmake 
    gperf 
    git 
    dbus-glib (dbus-glib-1.pc, required=0.98, installed=0.104)
    taglib (taglib.pc, required=1.5, installed=1.9.1)
    nss (nss.pc, required=3.12.11, installed=3.19.2.1)
    make 
    xorg-wacom (xorg-wacom.pc, installed=0.30.0)
    libXft (xft.pc, required=2.0.0, installed=2.3.2)
    libXcomposite (xcomposite.pc, installed=0.4.4)
    cups (required=1.4)
    gudev (gudev-1.0.pc, required=173, installed=230)
    mtdev (mtdev.pc, required=1.1.1, installed=1.1.5)
    wayland-egl (wayland-egl.pc, required=1.0, installed=11.0.2)
    libXrandr (xrandr.pc, required=1.3, installed=1.5.0)
    itstool 
    alsa (alsa.pc, required=1.0.19, installed=1.0.29)
    libXrender (xrender.pc, installed=0.9.9)
    exempi (exempi-2.0.pc, required=2.2.0, installed=2.2.2)
    hyphen 
    p11-kit (p11-kit-1.pc, required=0.19.0, installed=0.23.1)
    polkit-agent (polkit-agent-1.pc, required=0.102, installed=0.105)
    xcb (xcb.pc, required=1.10, installed=1.11)
    intltool (required=0.50)
    bison (required=2.4)
    libXcursor (xcursor.pc, installed=1.1.14)
    iptables 
    pkg-config 
    xcb-xkb (xcb-xkb.pc, required=1.10, installed=1.11)
    xorg-kbproto (kbproto.pc, installed=1.0.7)
    libacl 
    xkeyboard-config (xkeyboard-config.pc, installed=2.12)
    anthy (anthy.pc, required=9100h, installed=9100h)
    iso-codes (iso-codes.pc, required=3.51, installed=3.60)
    libpwquality (pwquality.pc, installed=1.2.3)
    json (json-c.pc, required=0.11, installed=0.11.99)
    polkit-gobject (polkit-gobject-1.pc, required=0.103, installed=0.105)
    readline 
    libcap 
    cairo (cairo.pc, required=1.14.0, installed=1.14.2)
    ppp 
    pam 
    libXfixes (xfixes.pc, installed=5.0.1)
    cc 
    libdmapsharing (libdmapsharing-3.0.pc, installed=2.9.31)
    libepoxy (epoxy.pc, required=1.2, installed=1.2)
    python2-devel (python-2.7.pc, required=2.7, installed=2.7)
    texinfo 
    libexif (libexif.pc, required=0.6.19, installed=0.6.21)
    ruby 
    libffi (libffi.pc, required=3.0.0, installed=3.2.1)
    libgcrypt (required=1.5.0)
    libcanberra (libcanberra-gtk.pc, required=0.30, installed=0.30)
    libgphoto2 (libgphoto2.pc, required=2.4.13, installed=2.5.8)
    libhangul (libhangul.pc, required=0.1.0, installed=0.1.0)
    libcanberra-gtk3 (libcanberra-gtk3.pc, installed=0.30)
    libicu (icu-i18n.pc, required=4, installed=55.1)
    c++ 
    WebKit1 (webkitgtk-3.0.pc, required=2.0.0, installed=2.4.9)
    libjpeg 
    wavpack (wavpack.pc, required=4.2, installed=4.75.0)
    xmlcatalog 
    sbc (sbc.pc, required=1.1, installed=1.3)
    libndp (libndp.pc, required=1.4, installed=1.4)
    xmllint 
    doxygen (required=1.8.1)
    xmlto 
    libnl-genl (libnl-genl-3.0.pc, required=3.2.7, installed=3.2.26)
    libXinerama 
    libX11 (x11.pc, installed=1.6.3)
    libnl (libnl-3.0.pc, required=3.2.7, installed=3.2.26)
    libnl-route (libnl-route-3.0.pc, required=3.2.7, installed=3.2.26)
    libmusicbrainz (libmusicbrainz5.pc, required=5.0, installed=5.1.0)
    libXi (xi.pc, required=1.7.4, installed=1.7.4)
    enchant (enchant.pc, required=1.6.0, installed=1.6.0)
    libdb 
    libXdamage (xdamage.pc, installed=1.1.4)
    speex (speex.pc, required=1.2rc1, installed=1.2rc1)
    automake 
    libpng (libpng.pc, installed=1.2.51)
    shared-mime-info (shared-mime-info.pc, required=1.0, installed=1.3)
    krb5 
    libproxy (libproxy-1.0.pc, installed=0.4.11)
    dvdread (dvdread.pc, required=4.2.0, installed=5.0.0)
    libatasmart (libatasmart.pc, required=0.17, installed=0.19)
    rapper 
    libtool 
    xorg-xproto (xproto.pc, required=7.0.28, installed=7.0.28)
    libdrm (libdrm.pc, required=2.4.45, installed=2.4.64)
    libsndfile (sndfile.pc, required=1.0.21, installed=1.0.25)
    xtrans (xtrans.pc, required=1.3.5, installed=1.3.5)
    bluez (bluez.pc, required=5.6, installed=5.35)
    sm (sm.pc, installed=1.2.2)
    libsystemd (libsystemd.pc, required=210, installed=225)
    flac (flac.pc, required=1.1.4, installed=1.3.1)
    libsystemd-daemon (libsystemd-daemon.pc, required=210, installed=225)
    wget 
    flex (required=2.0)
    xsltproc 
    plymouth (ply-boot-client.pc, required=0.8.9, installed=0.9.1)
    lcms2 (lcms2.pc, required=2.6, installed=2.6)
    fontconfig (fontconfig.pc, required=2.11.0, installed=2.11.1)
    libsystemd-login (libsystemd-login.pc, required=210, installed=225)
    wireless-tools (required=25)
    freetype2 (freetype2.pc, required=2.4.9, installed=17.1.11)
    smbclient (smbclient.pc, installed=0.2.1)
    libtasn1 (libtasn1.pc, required=2.7, installed=4.5)
    gbm (gbm.pc, installed=11.0.2)
    libXt (xt.pc, installed=1.1.5)
    libnice (nice.pc, required=0.1.8, installed=0.1.13)
    xwayland 
    libtool-ltdl 
    libevdev (libevdev.pc, required=1.2.2, installed=1.4.3)
    js24 (mozjs-24.pc, required=24.2, installed=24.2.0)
    libudev (libudev.pc, required=143, installed=225)
    avahi (avahi-gobject.pc, required=0.6.31, installed=0.6.31)
    liboauth (oauth.pc, required=0.9.4, installed=1.0.1)
    libusb1 (libusb-1.0.pc, required=1.0.19, installed=1.0.19)
    libXtst (xtst.pc, required=1, installed=1.2.2)
    libuuid (uuid.pc, installed=2.26.0)
    gettext-bin 
    zlib (zlib.pc, installed=1.2.8)
    libv4l (libv4l2.pc, installed=1.6.3)
    python-devel (python3.pc, required=3.2, installed=3.4)
    xcb-dri2 (xcb-dri2.pc, required=1.8.1, installed=1.11)
    gl (gl.pc, installed=11.0.2)
    libpinyin (libpinyin.pc, installed=1.0.0)
    libvpx (vpx.pc, installed=1.4.0)
    docbook-xsl 
    libxkbfile (xkbfile.pc, installed=1.0.9)
    libxklavier (libxklavier.pc, required=5.0, installed=5.4)
    startup-notification (libstartup-notification-1.0.pc, required=0.12, installed=0.12)
    gmime (gmime-2.6.pc, required=2.6.6, installed=2.6.20)
    libXext (xext.pc, installed=1.3.3)
    libxml2 (libxml-2.0.pc, required=2.7.8, installed=2.9.2)
    ragel 
    libxslt (libxslt.pc, required=1.1.26, installed=1.1.28)
    gnutls (gnutls.pc, required=3.1, installed=3.3.15)
    libarchive (libarchive.pc, required=3.0.0, installed=3.1.2)
    libyaml 
    mpfr 
    sqlite3 (sqlite3.pc, required=3.7.3, installed=3.8.11.1)
    libwebp 
    llvm 
    xorg-macros (xorg-macros.pc, installed=1.19.0)
Required packages:
  System installed packages which are too old:
    (none)
  No matching system package installed:
    rdflib 
    mesa-libGLES (glesv2.pc, required=9.2)
    poppler (poppler-glib.pc, required=0.24.0)
    libsystemd-journal (libsystemd-journal.pc, required=201)
    libtiff 
Optional packages: (JHBuild will build the missing packages)
  System installed packages which are too old:
    libical (libical.pc, required=1.0.1, installed=1.0)
    WebKit (webkit2gtk-4.0.pc, required=2.11.2, installed=2.8.5)
  No matching system package installed:
I: Installing dependencies on system: rdflib mesa-libGLES poppler libsystemd-journal libtiff
I: Using apt-file to search for providers; this may be slow.  Please wait.
I: No native package found for libsystemd-journal (/libsystemd-journal.pc)
I: No native package found for libtiff (/usr/include/tiff.h)
I: Installing: emscripten emscripten
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
emscripten is already the newest version.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

So what do I do? I tried the next step in the instructions but it says that it is missing some of the required packages. But as it seems that these packages are not in the repositories for my system, how do I install them?

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily
Flavour: GNOME
GNOME Version: 3.18
```

Comment: To build Gnome is strongly recommended to be using a distribution which has latest Gnome version. Latest Fedora is known to be well supported.

Comment: Use Docker: `docker pull fedora`. Run a docker container `docker run -it DOCKER_IMAGE_ID /bin/bash` and build GNOME inside this container.

Comment: @A.B.: Right, so is that the `docker.io` package then?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libsystemd-journal-dev libtiff5
```

might be easiest workaround, but using libsystemd-journal-dev makes libsystemd-journal.pc file in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libsystemd-journal.pc rather than /libsystemd-journal.pc, I dont know if it's a problem, you should try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case. The problem is [`libsystemd-journal` isn't available for 15.10+](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libsystemd-journal&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). Therefore I directly downloaded its .deb from my local mirror. In my case, [that is here](http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libsystemd-journal-dev_219-7ubuntu6_amd64.deb).

Comment: @KevinBowen Links to files are not the same things as a link-only answer. I have no doubt this answer could be better, but your auto-comment doesn't fit.

Comment: @Oli Reasonable point. I've removed my original comment. Thanks.